# Return the animation into its original postion

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to return all the images that has been slide, and return to its original position.
How can I make it return all the images to its original position? Thanks!

my code in js

```
    function animateFirst(){
        $('#slideimg > div:first').animate({left:"-=62px"},
        500,function(){
        $('#slideimg > div:first').delay(4500).animate({bottom:"-62px"},500).appendTo('#small-img1');

}
}
```

my html code

```
<div id="small-img1">
        <div id="slideimg">
            <div><img src="images/resize_1346910724.jpg" /></div>
            <div><img src="images/resize_1347348425.gif" /></div>
            <div><img src="images/resize_1347354705.png" /></div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out [this google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+animate+to+original+position) where the top **7 results** are duplicates of your question - *All* on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur to understand what you want to do (looking at your code) but to answer your title, you can reset position by saving original position (left offset and top offset) and animate your elements to previously saved position.

Answer (score 0):

on $("document").ready store all images and the positions to an array and then create a function to restore those values when called...
orrrr...

on $("document").ready copy the contents(html) of a wrapper div to a variable and then replace that divs contents with the original html when called...

many different ways to do it